# when i run gradlew dependencies in cmd i got these errors i tried but it does not work

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> Connecting to Daemon

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\gamefaar\android\build\build.gradle' line: 19
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.5'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.5')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google

### Gradle 8.5

Build time:   2023-11-29 14:08:57 UTC
Revision:     28aca86a7180baa17117e0e5ba01d8ea9feca598

Kotlin:       1.9.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          20 (Oracle Corporation 20+36-2344)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
java version 21

i tried but unable please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is no version 8.5 for the Android application plugin (see [repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.and#com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin)).

Choose a valid one eg ([Android docs](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.0' // add apply false if applicable
}
```

(If you follow the standard setup, this is in your root `build.gradle`.)